# Why will this for loop not return one field from list rather than the list?

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

import csv

"""sample row =  10/6/2010,73.42,74.43,72.9,74.15,2993500"""

filename_in = 'c:/python27/scripts/fiverows.csv'

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename_in, "rb"), dialect="excel", delimiter="\t", quoting  =csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in reader:  
    for item in row:  
        print 'row = ',row  
        print 'item  = ', item
```

When you run this script and print the row you get the sample row returned in [] as a list.
When you print the item you get the sample row as an unquoted string.  Why do I not get each field ie, (10/6/2010), (73.42), etc. returned as an item?  How do I return a single item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change delimiter from '\t' to ','.

Comment: Wonderful! It works.  You have no idea how many hours I've spent looking for this answer.